# string patterns to PCRE conversion code

Tags: pcre, snort

I would like to know, is there a conversion library for converting string patterns to PCRE regular Expression patterns.

Sample Patterns:

application/ms-tnef ARKADMIN_GET_ 34 ^MAIL FROM|3a| ?

2|

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

An online solution to find a Regex from string patterns is hosted on [this research project](http://regex.inginf.units.it/). You have only to provide some examples that covers the set of patterns you want to recognize. It's really important that this set is **meaningfull**.

---

The online tool is based [on this paper](http://machinelearning.inginf.units.it/publications/international-conference-publications/automaticgenerationofregularexpressionsfromexampleswithgeneticprogramming).

Answer (score 0):

PCRE/Regex is such a complicated morass of black magic and voodoo, that I think you'll be hard pressed to find an automated converter for it.  I've tried before.

[This blog post](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-generation) covers some of the reasons why.

That said, there is a website/tool called [txt2re](http://www.txt2re.com/) that might help you in getting the job done.  Or you can build some matching RegEx yourself using [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), an online, flash-based RegEx design and testing interface.